# Find and replace specific value in numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, iteration

I want to iterate through a numpy ndarray and, if any values are less than X, replace one of them with X.

I have tried doing `array_name[ array_name < X] = X` but this replaces all of the values that are less than X.

I can use a for loop, but I feel like there's probably a more concise way already bundled with numpy.

```
        for i in array_name:
            if i < X:
                i = X
                break
```

Is there a way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_name < X
```

Returns same array but with True or False. Then you can just pick an index where the cell is True

```
idx = np.argwhere(array_name < X)[i]
array_name[idx] = value
```

Here, you can choose `i` arbitrarily

Comment: What are you doing with `i` there?

Comment: Any index in `np.argwhere(array_name < X)` satisfies your constraint. So `i` is one of them